# Arraylist element name already exists, update otherwise create new one in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, wrapper

I have trying to get the string value from the arraylist values.

But In my arraylist if the value already exists , just update the count . otherwise need to create a new one. Here values are updating, but how can i create a new one element if the name didn't match with the arraylist element name?  Please tell me , how can i verify the element(GlobalData.getCRole) already exists in the arraylist.
In this code the arraylist name is GlobalData.getrolecount

```
 GlobalData.getCRole = item.getRole_name();
                if (GlobalData.getrolecount.size() > 0) {

                     for (int i = 0; i < GlobalData.getrolecount.size(); i++) {
                        Role getrc = GlobalData.getrolecount.get(i);
                         Role getrcverify = new Role();
                         getrcverify.setRole_name(GlobalData.getCRole);

                         if (getrc.getRole_name().equalsIgnoreCase(GlobalData.getCRole)) {
                             String inccount = GlobalData.getrolecount.get(i).getCount();
                            int getcount = Integer.parseInt(inccount) + 1;
                            getrc.setCount(Integer.toString(getcount));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Role getrc = new Role();
                    getrc.setRole_name(GlobalData.getCRole);
                    getrc.setCount("1");
                    GlobalData.getrolecount.add(getrc);
                }
```

Comment: Where is the list in the code you pasted? ??

Comment: Create a new Role object and add it to arraylist when it doesn't match.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpa I think `GlobalData.getrolecount` is the arraylist.

Comment: @ K Neeraj Lal ., ya ofcourse. but where i ahve to create a new role, i need a condition to verify right

Comment: @KrishnaVeni Add an else condition to equals check and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @GabeSechan's answer, here's a snippet that would help you:

```
//let's say you store your data in a Map called myHashMap

String keyToMatch = "your_key_here";        // replace this line with whatever code you use to get your key
if(myHashMap.containsKey(keyToMatch))       // Check if your map already contains the key
{
    int val = myHashMap.get(keyToMatch);
    myHashMap.put(keyToMatch, val++);       // Can be shrunken to a single line
}
else
{
    myHashMap.put(keyToMatch, 1);           // If it doesn't exist in the map, add it (with count 1)
}
```

This code can be shrunken much more because `Map<>` is a very robust tool. But I've written it in a way similar to your implementation so you can understand it better.

Let me know if you need further explanation or help trying to init `myHashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a different data structure.  A list isn't what you want.  You want a Map (probably a HashMap) of strings to Count, or of strings to Roles.  That way you can do O(1) searches to see if a role already exists, rather than an O(n) walk of the list, and checking if the role exists is a simple check to see if get returns null.